# How to Exclude Phrases to preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this text and I want to search the word "job" except the phrase "on the job training" or a list of phrases.
If I use this preg_match http://regexr.com/3dlo7

I get 3 results... but I want only the 1st and the 3rd

> This is a good job and this is on the job training. Nice job

Any ideas for the preg_match?

Comment: Try with assertions http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php `(?<!on the )\bjob\b(?! training)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you want to test a regex for PHP, don't use RegExr that is designed for Javascript, you can use instead [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) or [regex.larsolavtorvik.com](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/)

You can design your pattern like this:

```
\bjob\b(?!(?<=\bon the job) training\b)
```

and if you want to exclude other cases:

```
\bjob\b(?!(?<=\bon the job) training\b|(?<=\bthe job) I hate\b)
```

You can also use a `(*SKIP)(*F)` pattern *(that makes the subpattern to fail and forces characters already matched to be skipped)*, it can be more easy to write but it's less efficient *(due to the fact that the pattern has an alternation at the beginning)*:

```
\b(?:on the job training\b(*SKIP)(*F)|the job I hate\b(*SKIP)(*F)|job\b)
```

You can improve it a little using the *first character discrimination* trick to quickly fail on non-interesting positions:

```
\b(?=[otj])(?:on the job training\b(*SKIP)(*F)|the job I hate\b(*SKIP)(*F)|job\b)
```

Comment: Much more complete than mine, +1.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = 'This is a good job and this is on the job training. Nice job';
preg_match_all('/(?<!on the )\bjob\b(?! training)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => job
            [1] => job
        )

)
```

Comment: I will have a list of exclude phrases.. This is only for one.

Comment: @Michalis: That wasn't said in your question, please edit it to add some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: Writing this, it will exclude all words "job" preceded with "on the " and not followed with " training" and all words "job" not preceded with "on the " and followed with " training".

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:-

```
\bjob(?!\straining)\b
```

http://regexr.com/3dloj

After your comment you also want to exclude word before your word then use below regex:-

```
\b(?<!Nice\s)job(?!\straining)\b  // exclude Nice word
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g8h

`(?<!Nice\s)job` matches `Nice` `"job"` that is not preceded by an `"Nice "`, using negative lookbehind.

Comment: Almost.... I can add | with words after my word but I can't add exlude words before my word

Comment: If you wabt to ignore Nice word then use this regex:- **\b(?<!Nice\s)job(?!\straining)\b**